# IBM Connections , how to create GCD for ccm

Tags: connection, ibm-connections

I tried to run *createGCD.sh* but there is connection problem with this. it takes not the URI i want. I have url conserv.mycompany.local and it want to connect to conserv:9081. I tried to change uri.txt but it doesnt help.

Any help appreciated.

additional info.

```
 Geting connection to the Content Platform Engine URI : http://conserv:9081/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM ...
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger          
 (filenet_error.api.com.filenet.apiimpl.util.ConfigValueLookup). 
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

 FNRCA0031E: API_UNABLE_TO_USE_CONNECTION: The URI for server communication cannot be determined from the connection object http://conserv:9081/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM. Message was: conserv
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.cOpenMultipartOutputStream(ServiceSessionNst.java:236)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.cReqRespPath(ServiceSessionNst.java:134)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.executeChanges(ServiceSessionNst.java:71)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.SessionHandle.executeChanges(SessionHandle.java:130)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.callExecuteChanges(Session.java:144)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.executeChanges(Session.java:527)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.executeChange(Session.java:830)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.save(IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.java:86)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.save(IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.java:77)
    at ccmDomainTool.createP8Domain(Unknown Source)
    at ccmDomainTool.main(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: conserv
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an /etc/hosts entry for conserv that maps to conserv.mycompany.local

eg 172.27.0.10 conserv.mycompany.local  conserv

however, you should also think about looking at your system to see if your hostname for your node is conServ not conserv.mycompany.local